# Creating Fat Jars: What is the mods folder?

Tags: javafx, javafx-11

I'm just on:

> https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular

trying to create a jar I can run on other systems (that do not have the javafx libraries as would happen with a non-developer layman user) and they've told me to use this:

```
dir /s /b src\*.java > sources.txt & javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% -d mods/hellofx @sources.txt & del sources.txt
```

What is mods/
Where is that supposed to be? Are they talking about out/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc you have linked refers to this [sample](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/tree/master/CommandLine/Modular/CLI).

If you clone the sample, and follow instructions on how to compile and run the project, the first command can be divided in three parts:

```
dir /s /b src\*.java > sources.txt & \
javac --module-path %PATH_TO_FX% -d mods/hellofx @sources.txt & \
del sources.txt
```

The first part just gets all the Java files in the src path and adds that to `sources.txt` file:

```
C:\path\to\hellofx\src\module-info.java
C:\path\to\hellofx\src\hellofx\HelloFX.java
```

The second part calls the `javac` command (see [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/javac.html#GUID-AEEC9F07-CB49-4E96-8BC7-BCC2C7F725C9)) to compile the content of `sources.txt`, adding the required `--module-path` option to include the JavaFX modules, and also adding the output or *destination* `-d` option:

> **-d directory**
>
> Sets the destination directory for class files. If a class is part of a package, then javac puts the class file in a subdirectory that reflects the package name and creates directories as needed.

This means that we are going to compile `hellofx.HelloFX.java` into the directory `mods/hellofx`, resulting in:

```
C:\path\to\hellofx\mods\hellofx\module-info.class
C:\path\to\hellofx\mods\hellofx\hellofx\HelloFX.class
```

The third step will just remove the `sources.txt` file.

And now you can run your module:

```
java --module-path "%PATH_TO_FX%;mods" -m hellofx/hellofx.HelloFX
```

You can specify any directory for the output, of course, so you can change it to `out` or `build` for instance, but then make sure you modify it accordingly in the rest of the instructions.